# List method to delete last element in list as well as all elements

Tags: python, list, methods

I have an issue with clearing `list`s. In the current program, I have a method that clears a certain number of `list`s. This is rather inconvenient since during one part of the program where this method is used, it would be a lot more helpful if it only deleted the last element from the lists. Is there any way in which I can set index numbers as parameters to my method to solve this problem?

The code for the method

```
def clearLists(self):
    del self.Ans[:]
    del self.masses[:]
```

Whenever I want to use this method, I merely write `self.ClearLists()` and it deletes every element in a list.

Comment: I don't see the relation between the question title and body.

Comment: Sorry about that, that was a leftover from an old, unposted question, now fixxxed.

Comment: If you don't want to clear your lists, why would you call a method called `clearLists`?

Comment: Am I the only what that do not understand what are you looking for?

Answer (score 107):

you can use `lst.pop()` or `del lst[-1]`

`pop()` removes and returns the item, in case you don't want have a return use `del`

Comment: As `pop()` takes the current size of the array, is this still the optimal solution, as we will have to now find the length of the array each time?

Comment: yes it's optimal because python knows the size of the list. It's `O(1)`

Answer (score 13):

To delete the last element from the list just do this.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = a[:-1]
#Output [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: This is better that `del a[-1]` that doesn't work in my function for some reason.

Comment: it doesn't work because it doesn't work in place, it creates a new reference for `a`. Maybe not what you want.

Answer (score 11):

To delete the last element of the lists, you could use:

```
def deleteLast(self):
    if self.Ans:
        del self.Ans[-1]
    if self.masses:
        del self.masses[-1]
```